# How to utilise __next__ method in the context of a for-loop?

Tags: python, iterator

I want to choose between different iterator definitions which for convenience are encapsulated in an object that presents an iterator to the user.

Here's a simple code example:

```
class IterTest():
    def __init__(self, switch, ceiling=20):
        if switch=="even":
            self.iterator=self.even_iter()
        elif switch=="odd":
            self.iterator=self.odd_iter()
        else:
            self.iterator=self.sequential_iter()
        self.ceiling = ceiling

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iterator

    def __next__(self):
        finished=False
        while not finished:
            return str(next(self.iterator))+" --> I'm from next"

    def even_iter(self):
        i=-2
        finished=False
        while not finished:
            i+=2
            yield i
            if i > self.ceiling: finished = True

    def odd_iter(self):
        i=-1
        finished=False
        while not finished:
            i+=2
            yield i
            if i > self.ceiling: finished = True

    def sequential_iter(self):
        i=0
        finished=False
        while not finished:
            i+=1
            yield i
            if i > self.ceiling: finished = True
```

If I set this up, I can call the object via `next` to return the appropriate next element in the sequence:

```
r = IterTest("odd")
next(r)
>> "1 --> I'm from next"
next(r)
>> "3 --> I'm from next"
```

So far so good - but if I instead use the iterator in the context of a for-loop, then I get the following:

```
for t in r:
    print(t)
>> 5
>> 7
>> 9
>> 11
>> 13
>> 15
>> 17
>> 19
>> 21
```

What I was expecting was for the result to include the modification present in my `__next__` function, as per the `next(r)` calls. But these are skipped when called via a `for` construct.

Why is this, and how can I write a single modifier that will pre-process the output of an iterator irrespective of whether it's retrieved via a `next` or a `for` construct?

Comment: Your `IterTest` implementation is totally broken. `def __iter__` should return `self`. You have a weird mix of an iterable and an iterator. Basically, the behavior you are seeing is because a for-loop implicitly calls `iter` on your object, which for an iterator should return `self`, instead, you return `self.iterator`, which itself is *another* iterator, in this case, the iterator returned by `def  odd_iter(self)` (i.e. the generator). So the `__next__` method of that iterator is being called.

Comment: Ahh, OK - I see that - and when I change the `__iter__` call to return self, it behaves as expected. So that's great - thanks! I think I was trying to reinforce the idea of the iterator being something that can change, and wanted to be sure that `__iter__` would point to the right thing - but I guess the `__next__` call manages the machinery of what to return. Fantastic, thankyou.

Comment: Your `__next__` implementation also is strange, why is there a `while` loop *that will only ever have a single iteration*? It does not correctly handle `StopIteration`

Comment: My real use-case is for the switchable iterators to fetch content from various IO sources, and the `__next__` iterator to provide a single point of reference that might process the contents to some standard format, or to handle exceptions that might arrive. Interestingly, when I apply this __iter__ -> return self fix to my original code, it behaves as though there's an infinite loop, finally returning a bunch of Nones after working through the file contents. I think I was intending to catch a StopIteration error and set finished=True on that trigger.

Comment: ... But *why the while loop in `__next__`*? Do you not see that it's pointless? And actually, I think it does deal with `StopIteration` correctly.

Comment: But yes, I think I get the idea that the code in the next block only gets called once per iteration, so there's no need to wrap it in something that looks loopy in order for it to behave so. Lots of fuzzy thinking going on, which I think reflects my never having quite *got* iterators properly. This conversation is helping clear some of that up!